# Is there any way to show notification on an Android TV for API30 or higher?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-tv

I have an Android TV application which major feature is showing real-time notifications to users while they are watching TV. I actually used the following code to display users a notification;

```
View layout = View.inflate(MyApp.getAppContext(), R.layout.notification_layout, null);

TextView text = layout.findViewById(R.id.notification_text);
text.setText(mMessage);

ImageView image = layout.findViewById(R.id.notification_image);
image.setImageResource(mImageId);

Toast toast = new Toast(MyApp.getAppContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END, 30, 30);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

But as Android said the **setGravity** method doesn't work anymore for devices running **API30** or higher.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int)

As the detailed flow of my application;

1. I use the firebase cloud messaging service to get real-time events from the Android TV application.
2. When I send the data to the `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` URL, the Android TV app can get the message from the `onMessageReceived` function of the `FirebaseMessagingService` class.(I send data message instead of notificaion message because as I know Android TVs don't have notification try.)
3. After I get data message from the TV app, I display a notification by using the code above;

Now, I can't display the notificaion because of the Android API level limitations but I have to display the notification or something like notification to users because this is the major feature of my app. Now how can I inform user while they are waching TV and while the app running background. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have handled this problem by using WindowManager interface. My new notification displayer like the following;

```
WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) MyApp.getAppContext().getSystemService(MyApp.getAppContext().WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
                params.x = 0;
                params.y = 100;

View layout = View.inflate(MyApp.getAppContext(), R.layout.notification_layout, null);

TextView text = layout.findViewById(R.id.notification_text);
text.setText(mMessage);

ImageView image = layout.findViewById(R.id.notification_image);
image.setImageResource(mImageId);

mWindowManager.addView(layout, params);
```

This interface needs user permission to display the notification while my application runs in the background. When I give the `Display over other apps` permission from the apps menu of the TV, the notification feature of my app worked well.

I have also added the following permission into the manifest;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```